# Multiple similar dependent variables, each with the same set of idependent variables. How to find a generic model?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear, multivariate-regression

I have a number of similar dependent variables $y_i$, $i\in[1;10]$. Each $y$ has a number of corresponding independent variables $x_{ij}$, $j\in[1;20]$. Now I **would like to find some generic multiple linear model** $y=k_{1}x_{1}+...h_{20}x_{20}+c$ that applies to all of if $y$s. I looked at multivariate linear regression; however it seems that it has single set of $x_j$ for all $y_i$, rather than an individual $x_{ij}$ for each one $y_i$. I don't know what method to pursue to get the generic multiple linear equation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this situation.  It looks like you really have just *one* dependent variable $y$ along with $10$ collections of observations of it, and ditto for the independent variables.  If so, you are looking for a multiple regression solution.  How does your situation differ from this commonplace one?

Comment: @whuber Well the multiple regression solution would have only one $y$, wereas I have several $y_i$. Imagine that $y$ is the GDP of a country and that I have 10 different countries. I have also 20 independent variables associated with each country like unemployment rate, industrial output etc. Even though I could run multiple linear regressions for individual regressions, what I am interested in is a generic model that would explain GDP for all of the countries.

Comment: * "regressions for individual countries"